# angular wait for variable is defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 controllers and one service:

```
angular.module('objDescApp', ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap']);
angular.module('objDescApp').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$httpProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $httpProvider) {
                'use strict';
                $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

                $stateProvider
                .state('object', {
                   url: '/{name}',
                   views: {
                        "body": {
                            controller: 'ObjectDetailCtrl',
                            template: '...'
                        }
                });


angular.module('objDescApp').controller('ObjectListCtrl', function ($scope, $state, ConfigService) {
  ConfigService.getConfig(function(){//get config from server
   $scope.object = ConfigService.fillConfigForObjList(); //use config
  }
}

angular.module('objDescApp').controller('ObjectDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'ConfigService',  function ($scope, $stateParams, ConfigService) {
   $scope.current_object = ConfigService.fillConfigForObjDetail(); //use config
}

angular.module('objDescApp').factory('ConfigService', function ($http, $rootScope) {
  var jsonConf;
  var confTemplate = {"sometemplate" : {}};

  function fillConfigForObjList (){
     ... //use jsonConf variable , and always wait for init because of called only inside callback function of getConfig();
  };
  function fillConfigForObjDetail(){
    ... //use jsonConf variable , but doesnt wait for jsonConf  initialization, so error var 'is undefined' here.So I need to add some waiting for 'jsonConf' initialization logic here

   };

   return {
              jsonConf: jsonConf,
              fillConfigForObjDetail: fillConfigForObjDetail,
              fillConfigForObjList: fillConfigForObjList,
              getConfig: function(callback){           
                            $http({
                              method: 'GET',
                              url: endPointUrl,
                              transformResponse: undefined
                            }).then(
                                function successCallback(response) {
                                    jsonConf = JSON.parse(response.data);
                                    $rootScope.getConfigError = false;
                                    callback();
                                },
                                function errorCallback(response) {
                                    if(response.status == "404"){
                                        jsonConf = confTemplate;
                                    }else{
                                        console.log("Get config error");
                                        jsonConf = confTemplate;
                                        $rootScope.getConfigError = true;
                                    }
                                    callback();
                                }
                            );
                        }
    }
```

So, when I load page with main path **'/'** everything is OK, because '*ObjectListCtrl*' controller triggers *getConfig()* function which sets '*jsonConf*' variable after response, so I can naviagte between any states and all works fine cause 'jsonConf' already setted;

But If I re-load page with starting path state like **'/{name}'** , so '*ObjectListCtrl*' controller trigers *'getConfig()'* request to server , but in async way  *'ObjectDetailCtrl'* controller was triggered and its *$scope.current_object = ConfigService.fillConfigForObjDetail()* expression, which throw `jsonConf is undefined error;`
So could someone tell me how I can wait inside 'fillConfigForObjDetail()' function till 'jsonConf' variable init by getConfig() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save the promise and **chain** from the promise.

```
   var jsonConfPromise;

   function getConfig() {
       //save httpPromise           
       jsonConfPromise = $http({
                              method: 'GET',
                              url: endPointUrl,
                              transformResponse: undefined
                            }).then(
                                function successCallback(response) {
                                    jsonConf = JSON.parse(response.data);
                                    $rootScope.getConfigError = false;
                                    //return for chaining
                                    return jsonConf;
                                },
                                function errorCallback(response) {
                                    if(response.status == "404"){
                                        jsonConf = confTemplate;
                                    }else{
                                        console.log("Get config error");
                                        jsonConf = confTemplate;
                                        $rootScope.getConfigError = true;
                                    }
                                    //return for chaining
                                    return jsonConf;
                                }
                            );
       //return promise
       return jsonConfPromise;  
   };
```

Your function that had problems can then **chain** from the promise.

```
function fillConfigForObjDetail(){
    /*
    ... //use jsonConf variable , but doesnt wait for jsonConf
    initialization, so error var 'is undefined' here.
    So I need to add some waiting for 'jsonConf' initialization
    logic here
    */

    //chain from the promise
    jsonConfPromise.then(function (jsonConf) {
        //use resolved jsonConf
    });
};
```

Also in your controller instead of using a callback, **chain** from the returned promise.

```
angular.module('objDescApp').controller('ObjectListCtrl', function ($scope, $state, ConfigService) {
    var configPromise = ConfigService.getConfig();
    configPromise.then(function() {
         $scope.object = ConfigService.fillConfigForObjList();
    });
});
```

The AngularJS framework uses **promises** instead of **callbacks**.

For more information on **chaining promises**, see [AngularJS $q Service API Reference -- chaining promises](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises).

> Because calling the `then` method of a promise returns a new derived promise, it is easily possible to create a chain of promises. It is possible to create chains of any length and since a promise can be resolved with another promise (which will defer its resolution further), it is possible to pause/defer resolution of the promises at any point in the chain. This makes it possible to implement powerful APIs.<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#chaining-promises)</sup>